# write to BLE char_write_req

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor

I want to change notification so I did this:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic init_gatt=mConnectedGatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(CHAR_2_UUID);
                mConnectedGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(init_gatt,true);
                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = init_gatt.getDescriptor(
                        UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                boolean success=mConnectedGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                init_gatt.setValue(new byte[]{0x19});
                mConnectedGatt.writeCharacteristic(init_gatt);
```

So success is true, but onCharacteristicChanged() never gets called.
A collegue of min got it done on a pie with
Here I got an example of a gatttool write request.

```
gatttool -b <MAC Address> --char-write-req --handle=0x0031 --value=0100 --listen android
```

where the parameters are `char-write-req 0x16 01:00`

So is there a way to do the same in android?

Comment: The code that you've shown registers the characteristic for notifications, and since you received success on that `write`, you are now ready to receive notifications.  `onCharacteristicChanged` will get called when a notification of that characteristic is received, but the device your connected to sends that on it's own terms.

Comment: If you can also write to the characteristic (it has that property), then you should also receive a true or false result on the `writeCharacteristic` call as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **Android does not deal with handles**. I was obsessed to try to get a handle but I solved the problem with enabling the notification. I built a state machine in which I enabled every descriptor notification step by step and it works now. So my code generally was right but I had to repeat it when I got a successful enabled flag.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1y4tEHDwk0&list=PL2PAEHK-s-1UlXHzBhIP68yCsP8EOHgxJ) explains very good how you have to deal with it.